# What is the "closed circuit" of a bug swatter racket?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, electric-current, voltage, electrical-engineering

There are bug swatter racket that can kill fruit flies, mosquitos, or flies, if the insect touches the metal mesh.

However, when I look at the construction of the device, the metal mesh is all one piece, meaning it is all coneected.

We heard from physics class before: if a bird stands on a power transmission line, no matter it is 1000V or 10000V, the bird won't get electrocuted, because there is no "closed circuit", meaning there is no current that would go from the bird's body to the ground.

So likewise, the bug that touches the metal mesh, which is said to be 4000V as on Amazon, should not complete a closed circuit, and therefore the bug should not be killed.

These are the photos of the racket. The "electric" metal mesh is only one piece, so there is no "completing the circuit" involved:

[image]
[image]

The electric fence in the diagram is one piece, all connected together, so there is only one pole, not two poles. The safety fence is about 6mm away from the electric fence, and the fruit flies are only at most 2mm long or wide, so it cannot be due to current from the electric fence to the safety fence.

The following is a photo of the electric fence and the safety fence. We can see the electric fence is all connected as one piece, and it is quite far from the safety fence:

[image]

Comment: Some searching suggests that the "electric fence" contains two layers, and the circuit is completed when an insect bridges that gap. Do you own one of these, and you suspect there is only one actively charged layer? Your image is not a technical specification; for example, it doesn't include any electrical connections between the power supply in the handle and the electrified center piece(s).

Comment: Where did you get the distance between the safety fence and the electric fence? Did you measure this yourself? If not, where is this data available? Do you know for sure it works on fruit flies?

Comment: I own one, and I can see into the device at the Electric fence: it is criss-cross and it is not two layers. It is one layer and all connected. And I can look at the distance between the electric fence to the safety fence: it is about 6mm at least. There is no way a fruit fly can touch both sides.

Comment: @StefanieGauss Does it actually work on fruit flies? If so, does it always produce an audible zap when used on fruit flies?

Comment: Yes, it killed 25 fruit flies already. And yes, it produced quite a big zap sound. I just added a photo taken by macro zoom.

Answer (score 5):

the electric fence plate is at high voltage. the outer safety fences are at ground potential. when a bug bridges the gap established by the safety layer between the electric fence and the safety fence, it gets electrocuted with a "pop".

Comment: this is what I was thinking too: is it true that some electric spark device can create a spark even if there are two poles that are a couple of millimeters apart, but with high voltage? It is using "air" as part of the conductor, so in vacuum, it won't work. So for example, if it can create a spark in 3mm, then the device make use of the fact that between the electric fence and the safety fence, there is 5mm, and the bug provides the extra 2mm, to make it 3mm

Comment: I suppose I can experiment by buying an extra device, and then cut the safety fence away, or open up the device and see if the safety fence it wired to something (for ground), and cut that connection, and then see if the device can still work

Comment: @StefanieGauss "Safety fence" could be somewhat misleading. The high voltage is applied between the "electric fence" and the "safety fence", these grids are both equally essential components of the circuit. This circuit is floating; there is no "safe" ground, and electrically the "safety fence" isn't intrinsically safer.  It keeps you safe only because it doesn't allow you to touch both grids at the same time. You can also experiment by touching the electric fence with the tip of a screwdriver to see if anything happens, and then shorting the two grids with it which will produce a zap.

Answer (score 3):

Often the insect first touches the outer safety fence, and subsequently one or more of its flexible legs or a wing are pulled electrostatically to the high voltage plate, bridging the gap. Thus it is able to bridge a gap larger than its body length.